# Get unique objects at end of relationship for fetch results

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app, I have two entities, Page and Annotation. In my Core Data model, they have a one to many relationship: `Page <-->> Annotation`.

I am fetching on the Annotation object because I need to apply certain predicates, but ultimately want to get a unique set of Pages that are related to the Annotations that match the predicate.

How can I get a set of unique Page objects that have a relationship to the Annotations returned from the fetch? Is it possible to do it in one fetch? I have tried some things with `NSDictionaryResultType` but got errors, and ultimately, I want objects, not values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not want to use `NSDictionaryResultType` as that does not return objects.  What you want to do is use KVC after you have retrieved your `Annotation` instances like this:

```
NSArray *results = ...; //Your fetch of Annotation objects
NSArray *uniquePages = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.page"];
```

The `uniquePages` array will contain your unique collection of `Page` instances.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! Yes, I saw your comments on another question about not using `NSDictionaryResultType` when you want objects.